# Login with Facebook is not working even with correct test user logged in

Tags: android, facebook, flutter, oauth, facebook-login

I am trying to implement "login with facebook" button in my app.

I have registered my app, and also created test users for my app but trying to use my app while logged in with these test users shows
"User is not allowed to see the application.: The user is not allowed to see this application per the developer set configuration."

I'm correctly logged in as the test user in my mobile, both in the facebook app and the internet browser.

(And also this "In development" switch doesn't work for me. It shows a loading dialog for a while and then it disappears and nothing happens.
Take a look here: https://prnt.sc/vk3qqg)

Also I'm getting this message in the debug panel when my login screen is loaded (even without clicking on the 'login with facebook' button):

```
E/GraphResponse(29249): {HttpStatus: 400, errorCode: 100, subErrorCode: 33, 
errorType: GraphMethodException, errorMessage: Unsupported get request. Object 
with ID '1365719610250300' does not exist, cannot be loaded due to missing 
permissions, or does not support this operation. Please read the Graph API 
documentation at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api}
```

What should I do?

Thank you for reading.

Comment: Nice bookmarks in that screenshot, particularly the first one ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright! after a day of time wasting on this, it turns out I was using a wrong app id in my facebook-login sdk, don't know where the wrong one came from.
Now, I can login and that message in the debug panel is also not shown.

But that switch is still not working though.